# Spacy train in batch of sentences

Tags: spacy, named-entity-recognition

I was wondering if it is possible to train the ner model in batches of sentences instead of 1 sentence at a time - as it is done here: https://github.com/explosion/spacy/blob/master/examples/training/train_ner.py

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, spacy's NER is not desinged to handled bacth training. This link has more details.
https://spacy.io/api/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes